# How to get a list of all deleted unmerged branches in git/GITHUB?

Tags: git

A long time ago i made some work in a branch, which I deleted during a clean up. So I would like to get it back because the request came up again. I can't remember the exact branch name. I have been looking at [how to get git log display name of (deleted) branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114519/how-to-get-git-log-display-name-of-deleted-branches), but I can't find it in the logs.

Comment: even if the branchname is gone, the commits should still be there. Do you remember anything about the changes? If there was a unique string, variable name etc. you can search for in the entire history by using this command. `git log -S somestring`

Comment: Might be me. But it only seem to search merged branches

Comment: oh sorry. probably need `--all` with it as well.
`git log --all -S somestring`

Comment: Thanks that works. Restoring the changes with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git

Comment: Added it as an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is this command:

```
git log --all -S somestring
```

where somestring is a unique string, variable name etc. that can identify the commits in question.

Once you have the commit sha then you can recreate the branch using:

```
git checkout -b branch-name commit-sha
```

Answer (score 1):

I just write a node.js script [find-deleted-unmerged-branches](https://npmjs.com/package/find-deleted-unmerged-branches) to find deleted unmerged branches (may with a name or without a name).

You can have a try with

```sh
npx find-deleted-unmerged-branches /path/to/your/git/repo
```

Will output something like:

```sh
┌─────────┬─────────────┬───────────┐
│ (index) │    name     │    sha    │
├─────────┼─────────────┼───────────┤
│    0    │ '<unknown>' │ 'bf2ef40' │
│    1    │ '<unknown>' │ 'dc1a360' │
└─────────┴─────────────┴───────────┘
```

Then checkout to given commit shas, and check whether it's the deleted branch.